# Umbraco: The type or namespace library does not exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, umbraco

I've been sent a web site developed using Umbraco 4.7 which I've managed to open in VS 2012 Express for Web. When I build the solution, I get an error message

> The type or namespace name 'library' does not exist in the namespace 'Clientname.umbraco' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I'm new to Umbraco but was told I had everything I needed to build the project. In the Solution Explorer, in the References folder there is a listing for 'umbraco' and when I open the reference in the Object Explorer, 'library' is listed, so I can't understand why it can't be found. When I create a new class, add "using umbraco" at the top, it doesn't show 'library' when using intellisense.

I'd try installing Umbraco, but the only way I could do that is to open NuGet and let it create a new project. As this is a web site that is already live and in an older version of Umbraco, I don't think that's a viable option. There are also lots of macros, master pages and user controls the previous developer has done, which I don't want to recreate if possible.

Project details: .Net 4 application, VS 2012 Express for Web, Umbraco runtime v4.0.30319, Umbraco configuration status: 4.7.0

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: I have never used umbraco, but you could use RSharper tool for VisualStudio, to help you with adding missing libraries, it might help but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a clash in the naming of items in your project. The library class is accessed via umbraco.library and you have a namespace called Clientname.umbraco which is where it appears to be looking for the library class.